# Как отсортировать массив по нескольким условиям?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив содержащий n-ое количество объектов. У каждого объекта есть свойство дата (date), свойство принимающее булево значение(isTrue) и свойство, которое содержит определенный числовой коэффициент (value). 
Нужно сделать следующее: Найти в массиве всё объекты у которых одинаковое св-во date, и если среди них есть объекты равные по св-ву isTrue (т.е. например у нас 5 объектов с одинаковой датой и среди них 4 объекта с isTrue: true) то среди таких объектов найти объект с максимальным значением св-ва value и оставить его в изначальном массиве, остальные объекты из массива удалить. 
По частям вроде ничего сложного, не знаю как вместе всё собрать.
Сначала сгруппировал в объект по датам.

```
var getMaxValue = function(arr) {
  result = arr.reduce(function (b, a) {
            b[a.PLAN_DATE] = b[a.PLAN_DATE] || [];
            b[a.PLAN_DATE].push(a);
            return b;
        }, Object.create(null));

        return result;
    };
```

Каждое св-во объекта содержит все массивы с одинаковой датой, вот по ним и нужно выполнить 2 и 3 часть условия. 
Т.е. структура сейчас такая:

```
{
  01.02.2018: [date: '01.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 100],
  02.02.2018: [
              [date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 150], 
              [date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: false, value: 100], 
              [date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 200]
              ],
  итд.
}
```

Например для 02.02.2018 видно, что isTrue = true в двух случаях, значит берем то в котором наибольшее value (оставляем массив, остальные с true удаляем)

Изначальная структура:

```
[
  {date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 453},
  {date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 342},
  {date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: false, value: 234},
  {date: '01.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 200},
  {date: '03.02.2018', isTrue: false, value: 100}
]
```

Comment: "ничего сложного" - так покажите Ваши несложные попытки

Comment: пример неотсортированного и отсортированного в студию

Comment: Уже лучше ). Однако, данные, которые Вы показали, - это результат вызова `reduce` (и не являются правильно форматированным JSON-ом). Добавьте пример исходных данных.

Comment: это тогда не сортировка, а фильтрация, раз элементы в итоге удаляются

Comment: @ThisMan это сортировка по наибольшему value, и фильтрация по isTrue )

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант:

```js
const data = [
  {date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 453},
  {date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 342},
  {date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: false, value: 234},
  {date: '01.02.2018', isTrue: true, value: 200},
  {date: '03.02.2018', isTrue: false, value: 100}
]

const groupedByDate = data.reduce((result, el) => {
  const key = `${el.date}:${el.isTrue}`;
  if(!result[key]) {
    // если такого ключа нет, то просто добавляем элемент
    result[key] = el;
  } else if(result[key].value < el.value) {
    // иначе проверяем, а нужно ли перезаписать элемент
    result[key] = el;
  }

  return result;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(groupedByDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  { date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true,  value: 453 },
  { date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: true,  value: 342 },
  { date: '02.02.2018', isTrue: false, value: 234 },
  { date: '01.02.2018', isTrue: true,  value: 200 },
  { date: '03.02.2018', isTrue: false, value: 100 }
];

var getMaxValues = function(arr) {
  var lookup = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!arr[i].isTrue)
      continue;

    if (!lookup[arr[i].date] || arr[i].value > lookup[arr[i].date].value)
      lookup[arr[i].date] = { value: arr[i].value, index: i };
  }

  var indices = [];
  for (var key in lookup)
    indices.push(lookup[key].index);

  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (indices.indexOf(i) == -1)
      arr.splice(i, 1);
  }

  return arr;
};

var res = getMaxValues(data);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: если `isTrue=false`, то в результат этот элемент не должен попадать

Comment: @ThisMan "среди них есть объекты равные по св-ву isTrue"

Comment: @ThisMan ага, не только равные true, а совпадающие по isTrue и из них выбирается с наибольшим value.

Comment: @delawere2009 обновил тогда свой ответ